# how many layers of pcb i need to draw?

Tags: pcb, altium, eaglecad

I’ve just graduated from the electrical engineering faculty.

So as I  researched, most of the companies required PCB design in Altium/eagle or equivalent...but there is a question in my mind is,  how many layers of PCB should a new grad electrical engineer draw in this software? Or what kind of qualifications do I have to get a job as a new grad engineer? I can use Eagle and draw some of the circuits but some of my friends said “if you cannot draw less than 6 layers, you cannot get a job” so this kinda conversations makes me worried about this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's kinda like asking how many ingredients you have to use in a recipe to be a chef..

Comment: I think what you're asking is "when *routing* something, how few layers do I need to be able to squeeze it into". I wouldn't worry about it. It's terrible advice anyways because some designs simply won't fit on 6 layers. Obviously you don't want to always need 6 layers no matter what you are routing, but 6 layers is *very* generous for a lot of circuits. It also doesn't take into account stackups which can change how many signal layers you have. Six signal layers is *very very* generous and a 6 layer PCB probably has more than 16 layers in total. Useless advice you received.

Comment: A charitable interpretation of your friends' advice might be that if you don't have experience in layout of fairly complex boards your prospective employer isn't going to be especially enthused about paying you AND eating the cost of your mistakes while you gain expertise. Boards that **require** 6 layers are fairly complex or  have dense connections like BGAs. The only way to get experience is to actually design boards, have them made, discover & fix the inevitable errors until the error rate goes down. It's best to start with fewer layers because a spin in 6 layers is much more expensive.

Comment: The medical company I work for didn't ask me about how many layers I could use, in fact they didn't ask any PCB questions at all. They just whipped out a bunch of Altium schematics, pointed to parts and said "what's this bit here doing?". Unless you're applying for a layout-only position, the company likely cares a bit more about your understanding about what the circuit *does* instead of how many layers it needs. Where I work, we've got boards with 2, 4, 6, 8 and even ten copper layers. Use as many layers as needed to make a good board that works well, passes EMC regulations and is affordable

Comment: Your friend probably meant that you need to minimize number of signal layers. Most of our designs have 4 layers - 2 signal, power plane and ground plane. Easy PCBs have only 2.

Comment: If you can place components (for a non trivial design) well enough to do the job with a single layer, I'd be impressed...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are a beginner, start off with a simple circuit on a single layer. Do as much as you can on a single layer. If you feel that a single layer is not sufficient, move onto two layers but preferably distribute the network across both layers instead of allotting them disproportionately with so much more on the first layer than on the second.

Irrespective of what the application is, keep this in mind: try compacting the circuit and keep the number of layers to a bare minimum.

Answer (score 1):

More than 2 layer PCBs are needed in compact or complicated designs. Often when no BGA, or any smallest components are used it is enough to use 2 layer as long as  required size of PCB is achievable. By the way the routing itself is not so difficult as a proper schematic, or component placement design. So I advise not to worry about multi layers, layers are there to help you make compact routing!